# Disposable wrapped in a using statement, object is added to list but can still be accessed via the list from outside of the using statement. why?

Tags: c#, .net, list, using, idisposable

I have a class to handle sending of mail, the `MailMessage` is wrapped in a `using` statement then passed to a method which returns a bool indicating whether the send was successful. I then add the message to a list of messages if it failed.

For some reason I can access the message via the List from outside of the scope of the `using` statement. Am I misunderstanding the `List<T>.Add(T)` function? I was under the impression that it created a reference to the object.

I only encountered this situation as I forgot to remove the using statement when refactoring to use the list to retry sending after a period of time.

```
private List<MailMessage> messageList;
using(MailMessage mess = new MailMessage(sender, recipient))
{
    DoStuff();
    if(!SendMessageConfirmation(mess))
    {
        messageList.Add(mess)
    }
}

// I expected this to throw an exception, but it does not.
Console.WriteLine(messageList[0].Sender);
```

I do realise that in the event of the message send succeeding an index out of range exception will throw, this is not exactly how I implement the code - just an example.

Comment: You are trying to access it out of scope. When it is disposed it (outside of using) you can no longer access it.

Comment: You want that the list must be cleared in last statement `Console.WriteLine(messageList[0].Sender);`

Comment: Looking at the [source code of the MailMessage class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/MailMessage.cs) it seems like not all properties will throw an `ObjectDisposedException` on access after disposing the instance (on a first look it seems like only the getters of the `Attachments` and the `AlternateViews` properties will throw when trying to access them on an already disposed instance)

Comment: Classes that implement `IDisposable` are not required to detect when you're using them improperly and throw exceptions when you do. Nevertheless, because `MailMessage` explicitly documents that "the `Dispose` method leaves the `MailMessage` in an unusable state" you are still not *supposed* to do this. (Merely adding the message to the list for later comparison by reference would be fine, though, as this doesn't access any member of the class.)

Comment: Why would you expect an exception there? `messageList` is in scope, so adding a new `MailMessage` instance to it, will create a reference to the `MailMessage` that will not be collected for as long as `messageList` (or anything else with a reference to it) are not collected.  `using` only guarantees that `Dispose` will be called, it doesn't get rid of any references or instances.

Comment: Don't get confused by the difference between the variable `mess` and the instance of `MailMessage` it holds a reference to.  They have different lifetimes.  `mess` is in scope for the duration of the `using` statement, but the instance of `MailMessage` will stay alive as long as *anything* has a reference to it, in this case, `messageList` is still in scope, holding the reference, and preventing the garbage collector from collecting the instance.

Comment: @KingChezzy no, I extended the scope by adding it to the list. @Agent_Orange not what I was trying to do.
@bassfader good shout, does this not mean that `MailMessage` has a poor `IDisposable` implementation?
@jeroen true, but I had assumed that the class would have properly released unmanaged resources given that it is part of .NET
@Bradley the question wasn't about scope, in essence it was about being able to call methods and properties of a disposed .NET object.

For the record I'd say this question is different to the linked one as this is a .NET class not a poorly written user class.